# res.sendFile() isn't doing anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using node.js, express, request-promise, and I'm writing a `server.js` file. In the `.then` statement, I have `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/thanks.html');` and it seems not to be doing... well anything. When I inspect using Chrome's dev tools and looking at the network tab, I never receive anything called `thanks.html` on the client at all. There isn't a problem with `rp(slackPost)` because I properly receive the message in Slack. `console.log('Worked!');` and `console.log('sent');` both work perfectly fine. Am I using the `res.sendFile()` function incorrectly?

Here's the relevant section of my `server.js` file:

```
app.post('/contact_us', function (req, res) {
//send input to Slack

// console.log('Working.');
// console.log(req.body);

//sets options to create a POST request (request-promise) to send the stuff to slack
var slackPost = {
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/API/key/here',
    body: '{\x22text\x22:\x22' + req.body.fname + '\n' + req.body.email + '\n' + req.body.info + '\x22}',
    json: false // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};

// console.log('Still working.');

rp(slackPost)
    .then(function (parsedBody) {
        // POST succeeded...
        console.log('Worked!');
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/thanks.html');
        // res.redirect('public/thanks.html');
        // res.json(null);
        console.log('sent');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // POST failed...
        // console.log('Failed :(');
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

And here's the script that runs on submit:

```
function sendToSlack() {
var fname = document.forms["contact"]["fname"].value;
var email = document.forms["contact"]["email"].value;
var info = document.forms["contact"]["info"].value;
var formInput = {
    fname: fname,
    email: email,
    info: info
};

fetch('/contact_us', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify(formInput)
})
.then(function(res) {
    window.location.replace('public/thanks.html');
    console.log('Posted');
} )
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log('problem');
} );
}
```

Comment: "*I never receive anything called `thanks.html` [..]*" – `res.sendFile()` just sends the contents of the file, not its name (unless `Content-Disposition` is used – i.e. `res.download()`). Do you able to see its contents in the response for the request to `/contact_us`?

Comment: If you want the file to be requested by name, try `res.redirect('/thanks.html')` in place of `res.sendFile()` (note: assuming you have `express.static()` serving files in `public`).

Comment: I cannot see its contents. In fact the only thing that happens is a `fetch` to `/contact_us` that has a `cancelled` tag next to it. That fetch happens in my client-side `js` file to send the user inputs to the server. I don't see anything from the server at all. Immediately after that fetch happens, I receive the "contact_us" page once again, but with the user input appended to the URL.

Comment: If it's cancelled, then the client stopped waiting for a response. Is the `fetch()` started when a `<form>` is submitted? The form may still be carrying out its normal submission as well, which will interrupt the `fetch()` by leaving the current instance of the page. [You can prevent this through the form's `submit` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission) – either `return false` or call `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @burnst14 so you're making an AJAX request (using fetch) and expect that the HTML is being shown somehow?

Comment: Following up and the above comment, if you are making this request via JS, then you need to handle the HTML response data from the same JS function that made the original request.

Comment: Yeah, @love is right. Alternatively, you can redirect _client side_ to a "thank you" page.

Comment: I've add the script that runs on submit. Hopefully this helps you understand what's happening.

Comment: Your form is doing a postback, which is canceling the ajax request. In other words, you're failing to prevent the default action from occurring, and the default action is interrupting your ajax request.

Comment: It doesn't appear as though you need ajax at all in this situation. By removing it and having the form post directly to the endpoint, you can allow the server to perform the redirect and remove a good portion of client-side code. (assuming your server-side endpoint can accept formparams)

Comment: Well I need to protect my API key, so I have to postback so I can process and do the send from the server. Does your solution still work in that case?

Comment: Yes, the apikey would still be on your server only. by "the endpoint" i meant your server endpoint that performs the request to slack.

Comment: Okay so you're suggesting a change to the client side code. How can I do this? Sorry, I'm new to webdev.

Comment: action="/contact_us" and stop listening to the submit/click event.

Comment: @KevinB Okay so I don't know how to receive the params now. And the URL didn't change, only the page content.

Comment: @KevinB, make that an answer and I'll mark it as solution. Working now! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding a path.join() to that send?
Like this:

```
var path = require('path');

...

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/thanks.html'));
```

It may also be that you need your app to use express.static()

Comment: Can you elaborate on what express.static() does?
`path.join()` did not work.

Comment: I looked into it and my file already has express.static() set up. Thanks though.

Comment: What the express.static() middlewre does is that it lets you serve static files such as images, css, html, etc... Now, are you sending any parameters to the static function? You should send the route that leads to your public directory, or the directory that has your static files. Could be something like static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')),